# Adding multilangage to module PrestaShop

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.5

I create simple module for displaying string in lef column it's works but I want extend it to possibility adding this text in all available language in my shop. Right now i module configuration page I have only input for string, how can I add next to this button with language selection and how save it in to database?

```
   if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_')) {
exit;
}

class Sometext extends Module
{
protected $config_form = false;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->name = 'sometext';
    $this->tab = 'front_office_features';
    $this->version = '1.0.0';
    $this->author = 'AgnesTom';
    $this->need_instance = 1;

    /**
     * Set $this->bootstrap to true if your module is compliant with bootstrap (PrestaShop 1.6)
     */
    $this->bootstrap = true;

    parent::__construct();

    $this->displayName = $this->l('sometext');
    $this->description = $this->l('some text in left column');
}

/**
 * Don't forget to create update methods if needed:
 * http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Enabling+the+Auto-Update
 */
public function install()
{
    Configuration::updateValue('SOMETEXT_TEXT', false);

    return parent::install() &&
        $this->registerHook('header') &&
        $this->registerHook('backOfficeHeader') &&
        $this->registerHook('displayLeftColumn');
}

public function uninstall()
{
    Configuration::deleteByName('SOMETEXT_TEXT');

    return parent::uninstall();
}

/**
 * Load the configuration form
 */
public function getContent()
{
    /**
     * If values have been submitted in the form, process.
     */
    if (((bool)Tools::isSubmit('submitSometextModule')) == true) {
        $this->postProcess();
    }

    $this->context->smarty->assign('module_dir', $this->_path);

    $output = $this->context->smarty->fetch($this->local_path.'views/templates/admin/configure.tpl');

    return $output.$this->renderForm();
}

/**
 * Create the form that will be displayed in the configuration of your module.
 */
protected function renderForm()
{
    $helper = new HelperForm();

    $helper->show_toolbar = false;
    $helper->table = $this->table;
    $helper->module = $this;
    $helper->default_form_language = $this->context->language->id;
    $helper->allow_employee_form_lang = Configuration::get('PS_BO_ALLOW_EMPLOYEE_FORM_LANG', 0);

    $helper->identifier = $this->identifier;
    $helper->submit_action = 'submitSometextModule';
    $helper->currentIndex = $this->context->link->getAdminLink('AdminModules', false)
        .'&configure='.$this->name.'&tab_module='.$this->tab.'&module_name='.$this->name;
    $helper->token = Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminModules');

    $helper->tpl_vars = array(
        'fields_value' => $this->getConfigFormValues(), /* Add values for your inputs */
        'languages' => $this->context->controller->getLanguages(),
        'id_language' => $this->context->language->id,
    );

    return $helper->generateForm(array($this->getConfigForm()));
}

/**
 * Create the structure of your form.
 */
protected function getConfigForm()
{
    return array(
        'form' => array(
            'legend' => array(
            'title' => $this->l('Settings'),
            'icon' => 'icon-cogs',
            ),
            'input' => array(
                array(
                    'col' => 3,
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'prefix' => '<i class="icon icon-envelope"></i>',
                    'desc' => $this->l('Enter a text'),
                    'name' => 'SOMETEXT_TEXT',
                    'label' => $this->l('Email'),
                ),
            ),
            'submit' => array(
                'title' => $this->l('Save'),
            ),
        ),
    );
}

/**
 * Set values for the inputs.
 */
protected function getConfigFormValues()
{
    return array(
        'SOMETEXT_TEXT' => Configuration::get('SOMETEXT_TEXT', 'Some text here'),
    );
}

/**
 * Save form data.
 */
protected function postProcess()
{
    $form_values = $this->getConfigFormValues();

    foreach (array_keys($form_values) as $key) {
        Configuration::updateValue($key, Tools::getValue($key));
    }
}

/**
* Add the CSS & JavaScript files you want to be loaded in the BO.
*/
public function hookBackOfficeHeader()
{
    if (Tools::getValue('module_name') == $this->name) {
        $this->context->controller->addJS($this->_path.'views/js/back.js');
        $this->context->controller->addCSS($this->_path.'views/css/back.css');
    }
}

/**
 * Add the CSS & JavaScript files you want to be added on the FO.
 */
public function hookHeader()
{
    $this->context->controller->addJS($this->_path.'/views/js/front.js');
    $this->context->controller->addCSS($this->_path.'/views/css/front.css');
}

public function hookDisplayLeftColumn()
{
   $some_string = Configuration::get('SOMETEXT_TEXT');
    if (isset($some_string)) {
    $this->context->smarty->assign('some_string', $some_string);
        return $this->display(__FILE__, '/views/templates/front/front.tpl');
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I am not able to get me a demo , which PrestaShop version are you using?

Comment: I'm edited code above now it's correct, it supposed to work in 1.5 and 1.6 version of prestashop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change in this way:

```
<?php

if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_')) {
    exit;
}

class Sometext extends Module
{
    protected $config_form = false;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->name = 'sometext';
        $this->tab = 'front_office_features';
        $this->version = '1.0.0';
        $this->author = 'AgnesTom';
        $this->need_instance = 1;

        /**
         * Set $this->bootstrap to true if your module is compliant with bootstrap (PrestaShop 1.6)
         */
        $this->bootstrap = true;

        parent::__construct();

        $this->displayName = $this->l('sometext');
        $this->description = $this->l('some text in left column');
    }

    /**
     * Don't forget to create update methods if needed:
     * http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Enabling+the+Auto-Update
     */
    public function install()
    {

        $languages = Language::getLanguages(false);

        foreach ($languages as $lang)
        {
            //$values[] = Tools::getValue('SOMETEXT_TEXT_'.$lang['id_lang']);
            Configuration::updateValue('SOMETEXT_TEXT_'.$lang['id_lang'], '');
        }

        return parent::install() &&
            $this->registerHook('header') &&
            $this->registerHook('backOfficeHeader') &&
            $this->registerHook('displayLeftColumn');
    }

    public function uninstall()
    {
        $languages = Language::getLanguages(false);

        foreach ($languages as $lang)
        {
            //$values[] = Tools::getValue('SOMETEXT_TEXT_'.$lang['id_lang']);
            Configuration::deleteByName('SOMETEXT_TEXT_'.$lang['id_lang']);
        }

        return parent::uninstall();
    }

    /**
     * Load the configuration form
     */
    public function getContent()
    {
        /**
         * If values have been submitted in the form, process.
         */
        if (((bool)Tools::isSubmit('submitSometextModule')) == true) {
            $this->postProcess();
        }

        //$this->context->smarty->assign('module_dir', $this->_path);

        //$output = $this->context->smarty->fetch($this->local_path.'views/templates/admin/configure.tpl');

        //return $output.$this->renderForm();
        $this->context->smarty->assign('form', $this->renderForm());
        return $this->display(__FILE__, '/views/templates/admin/configure.tpl');
    }

    /**
     * Create the form that will be displayed in the configuration of your module.
     */
    protected function renderForm()
    {
        $helper = new HelperForm();

        $helper->show_toolbar = false;
        $helper->table = $this->table;
        $lang = new Language((int)Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT'));
        $helper->default_form_language = $this->context->language->id;
        $helper->module = $this;
        //$helper->allow_employee_form_lang = Configuration::get('PS_BO_ALLOW_EMPLOYEE_FORM_LANG', 0);
        $helper->allow_employee_form_lang = Configuration::get('PS_BO_ALLOW_EMPLOYEE_FORM_LANG') ? Configuration::get('PS_BO_ALLOW_EMPLOYEE_FORM_LANG') : 0;

        $helper->identifier = $this->identifier;
        $helper->submit_action = 'submitSometextModule';
        $helper->currentIndex = $this->context->link->getAdminLink('AdminModules', false)
            .'&configure='.$this->name.'&tab_module='.$this->tab.'&module_name='.$this->name;
        $helper->token = Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminModules');

        $helper->tpl_vars = array(
            'fields_value' => $this->getConfigFormValues(), /* Add values for your inputs */
            'languages' => $this->context->controller->getLanguages(),
            'id_language' => $this->context->language->id,
        );

        return $helper->generateForm(array($this->getConfigForm()));
    }

    /**
     * Create the structure of your form.
     */
    protected function getConfigForm()
    {
        return array(
            'form' => array(
                'legend' => array(
                'title' => $this->l('Settings'),
                'icon' => 'icon-cogs',
                ),
                'input' => array(
                    array(
                        'col' => 3,
                        'type' => 'text',
                        'prefix' => '<i class="icon icon-envelope"></i>',
                        'desc' => $this->l('Enter a text'),
                        'name' => 'SOMETEXT_TEXT',
                        'label' => $this->l('Email'),
                        'lang' => true
                    ),
                ),
                'submit' => array(
                    'title' => $this->l('Save'),
                ),
            ),
        );
    }

    /**
     * Set values for the inputs.
     */
    protected function getConfigFormValues()
    {

        $languages = Language::getLanguages(false);
        $values = array();

        foreach ($languages as $lang)
        {
            if(Tools::getValue('SOMETEXT_TEXT_'.$lang['id_lang'])) $values['SOMETEXT_TEXT'][$lang['id_lang']] = Tools::getValue('SOMETEXT_TEXT_'.$lang['id_lang']);
        }
        return $values;

    }

    /**
     * Save form data.
     */
    protected function postProcess()
    {
        $form_values = $this->getConfigFormValues();

        foreach ($form_values['SOMETEXT_TEXT'] as $k=>$key) {  
            Configuration::updateValue('SOMETEXT_TEXT_'.$k, $key);
        }
    }

    /**
    * Add the CSS & JavaScript files you want to be loaded in the BO.
    */
    public function hookBackOfficeHeader()
    {
        if (Tools::getValue('module_name') == $this->name) {
            $this->context->controller->addJS($this->_path.'views/js/back.js');
            $this->context->controller->addCSS($this->_path.'views/css/back.css');
        }
    }

    /**
     * Add the CSS & JavaScript files you want to be added on the FO.
     */
    public function hookHeader()
    {
        $this->context->controller->addJS($this->_path.'/views/js/front.js');
        $this->context->controller->addCSS($this->_path.'/views/css/front.css');
    }

    public function hookDisplayLeftColumn()
    {
       $some_string = Configuration::get('SOMETEXT_TEXT_'.$this->context->language->id);
        if (isset($some_string)) {
        $this->context->smarty->assign('some_string', $some_string);
            return $this->display(__FILE__, '/views/templates/front/front.tpl');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's works correctly in front office but in configuration page is Notice Undefined index: SOMETEXT_TEXT_ so all input when I switch language are blank. I think there is something wrong in function getConfigFormValues()

Comment: I upgraded functions, watch now!